# Read Kotlin function annotation value using reflection?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-reflect

Given an interface method like this (Android Retrofit), how do I read the URL path specified in the annotation argument from Kotlin code at runtime?

ApiDefinition interface:

```
@GET("/api/somepath/objects/")
fun getObjects(...)
```

Read the annotation value:

```
val method = ApiDefinition::getObjects.javaMethod
val verb = method!!.annotations[0].annotationClass.simpleName ?: ""
// verb contains "GET" as expected
// But how to get the path specified in the annotation?
val path = method!!.annotations[0].????????
```

UPDATE 1

Thanks for answers. I'm still struggling as I can't see what type to use to do the following:

```
val apiMethod = ApiDefinition::getObjects
```

.... then to pass that function reference into  a method like this (it's reused)

```
private fun getHttpPathFromAnnotation(method: Method?) : String {
    val a = method!!.annotations[0].message
}
```

IntelliJ IDE is suggesting I use KFunction5<> as a function parameter type (it doesn't exist as far as I can see) and seems to be requiring I specify all the parameter types for the method too, which makes a generic call to get the annotation attribute impossible. Isn't there a Kotlin equivalent of "Method"?, a type that will accept any method? I tried KFunction, without success.

UPDATE 2

Thanks for clarifying things. I've got to this point:

ApiDefinition (Retrofit interface)

```
@GET(API_ENDPOINT_LOCATIONS)
fun getLocations(@Header(API_HEADER_TIMESTAMP) timestamp: String,
                 @Header(API_HEADER_SIGNATURE) encryptedSignature: String,
                 @Header(API_HEADER_TOKEN) token: String,
                 @Header(API_HEADER_USERNAME) username: String
                 ): Call<List<Location>>
```

Method to retrieve annotation argument:

```
private fun <T> getHttpPathFromAnnotation(method: KFunction<T>) : String {
    return method.annotations.filterIsInstance<GET>().get(0).value
}
```

Call to get the path argument for a specific method:

```
    val path = getHttpPathFromAnnotation<ApiDefinition>(ApiDefinition::getLocations as KFunction<ApiDefinition>)
```

The implicit cast seems to be necessary or the type parameter demands I provide a KFunction5 type.

This code works, but it has the GET annotation hard-coded, is there a way to make it more generic? I suspect I might need to look for GET, POST and PUT and return the first match.

Comment: `KFunction` should work. `private fun <T> getHttpPathFromAnnotation(method: KFunction<T>?)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the Kotlin [`KFunction`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-function/index.html) *directly* instead of `javaMethod` (you're using Kotlin anyway!), and [`findAnnotation`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect.full/find-annotation.html) for concise, idiomatic code.

This will also work if the annotation happens to not be the first, where `annotations[0]` may break.

```
val method = ApiDefinition::getObjects

val annotation = method.findAnnotation<GET>() // Will be null if it doesn't exist

val path = annotation?.path
```

Basically all `findAnnotation` does is return

```
annotations.filterIsInstance<T>().firstOrNull()
```